Should WASB be used to mount Azure Blob Storage in Databricks?
Using Databricks Premium, I need to make storage accounts accessible in dbt. Some of the storage accounts may use SAS tokens for credentials, so managed identities are not always an option.
What I've been able to do is to mount containers using WASB and this works ok. Only that WASB is apparently legacy and Unity Catalog should be preferred over mounting. I have been able to use neither ABFS, nor Unity Catalog.
There are two key constraints to the problem

Credentials shouldn't be in the cluster config. There are two reasons for this:

There are many clusters, sometimes created ad-hoc. Maintaining the configuration with multiple credentials seems infeasible.
The clusters may run jobs requiring differing access rights to the same resource. i.e. some are read-only, others have write access.


The jobs cannot provide credentials.

While a notebook could just do a few SET some.config=secret(scope,key), dbt doesn't seem to support injecting SQL before each query. And while this would be technically possible, it would make more sense to manage the credentials completely in Databricks.



The storage accounts may or may not be ADLS Gen 2 (i.e. storage accounts with hierarchical namespaces enabled).
In either case, if I set the necessary Spark config variables, the blobs are accessible using ABFS (E.g. with spark.read.parquet("abfss://...")). But when trying to mount using SAS token, I get the error
Unsupported Azure Scheme: abfss. In a related question, one answer infers that only OAuth credentials might be supported.
Further, Microsoft seems to indicate that ABFS can only be used with hierarchical namespaces enabled. This appears to be true in that using OAuth with a regular storage account (i.e. no HNS), mounting fails with this cryptic error message:
This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.

Unity Catalog doesn't seem to have any option at all to use credentials other than managed identities.

What is the appropriate way to enable access to blob storage?

The legacy WASB driver is deprecated, and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 is being retired. Databricks recommends using Unity Catalog for managing storage connections. Alternatively, you can mount Azure storage using a Microsoft Entra ID application service principal for authentication, or use the ABFS driver with hierarchical namespaces enabled for mounting containers using SAS tokens.

@Bhavani ADLS Gen 1 is retired, but AFAIK there is no announced plan to retire regular blob storage in favour of HNS enabled blob storage (though I wouldn't be surprised if that was going to happen). And as I mentioned, you cannot mount using abfss and SAS tokens.

After considering the options, I've come up with the following:
Prefer ABFS & ADSL Gen 2 with Managed Identities when possible. The downside is that presently ADSL Gen 2 does not support versioning or point-in-time restore. Soft Delete is the only supported data protection feature. A Legal Hold can be used for write protection with some difficulty.
Mount regular storage accounts & accounts with SAS credentials using WASB. Downside is that any external tables registered over data in these will only be in hive_metastore, which has certain performance issues and compatibility problems with Unity Catalogs.
